# NebulaGraph Database: when I filter edges by their property values, it shows incorrect results

Tags: nebula-graph

Here are some details:

- NebulaGraph version is 3.2.1
- Deployment way is distributed
- Installation way is RPM
- Disk is Non-SSD
- CPU and memory information are Single node 4core8g
  Specific description of the problem

I use the following nGQL to query the 2-hop path data with vid of 76517618765348

```
MATCH p=(v)-[e:`belong`*2]-(v2) 
WHERE id(v) IN ["76517618765348"] 
    AND ALL(l IN e WHERE  l.create_long == 1665368234) RETURN p LIMIT 100
```

The results are as shown in the figure below
[image]

Among them, the edge `belong` has the property of which type is `long` and name `create_long`. When I use the == to query the edge with a value of 1665368234 to filter. Why can’t I find the corresponding data?

The real data relationship is as shown in the figure below
[image]

Comment: Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to **add a transcription** of your image of the results in textual form? Perhaps useful: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you would like to filter all edges with this WHERE clause: `WHERE l.create_long == 1665368234`?

```
MATCH p=(v)-[e:`belong`*2]-(v2) 
WHERE id(v) IN ["76517618765348"] 
    AND ALL(l IN e WHERE l.create_long == 1665368234) RETURN p LIMIT 100
```

As you are using `==` here, I guess maybe you actually would like to express one of the edge in list of e fulfills `create_long == 1665368234`?

If it’s the case as I guessed, you should instead use `ANY` instead of `ALL` here:

And that is:

```
MATCH p=(v)-[e:`belong`*2]-(v2) 
WHERE id(v) IN ["76517618765348"] 
    AND ANY(e_ IN e WHERE e_.create_long == 1665368234)
RETURN p LIMIT 100
```